# angularjs detect changes in input when value is modified by JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a input (text + button). When I press the button (select date and time) and the library set value in input text. I like to detect changes with angularJs or JQuery for this field but it does not work.

I tried with (in directive):

```
$scope.$watch('namevarmodel', function() {
    alert('test');
},true);
```

And JQuery:

```
<script>
    $('#nameinput').change(function() {
        alert( "test." );
    });
</script>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why would you do this with JQuery?  Why wouldn't you just use the ng-click directive ... call a function that updates the model directly rather than changing the value of the input?  AngularJs is a full blown framework.  I find very few instances where I need to go outside that framework to use JQuery

Comment: You should never use jQuery inside an AngularJS application. AngularJS has jQuery Lite support internally if you're using directives. As @jbrown said, use the tools provided by the framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular provides directives that automagically keeps watching your inputs. You could check the angular documentation for ng-change and you could do something like this:

```
<input ng-change="action()">...</input>
```

I hope this helps.